# Умножение элементов массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Здравствуйте, как умножить каждый элемент массива по очереди на каждый элемент другого массива?

Например, есть массив `А[5]` и `B[5]`, и нужно умножить
`A[0]*B[0]`, `A[0]*B[1]`, `A[0]*B[2]`, ... потом
`A[1]*B[0]`, `A[1]*B[1]`, `A[1]*B[2]`, ...

Как это сделать в цикле?

Comment: Поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему?

Comment: Не понимаю как реализовать такое умножение в цикле

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        A[i]*B[j];
```

:)

Comment: интересно какой вопрос ТС задаст следующим :)